# Select that fill null fields using the id and the values of the same column

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this:

```
  PK |  IDs | name1 | name2
    -------------------
   1 |  1   |  a    | null  
   2 |  1   |  a    |  x
   3 |  2   |  b    | null  
   4 |  3   |  c    |  z
   5 |  2   | null  |  y
   6 |  1   | null  |  x
   7 |  2   |  b    | null
   8 |  2   | null  | null
```

And i want to execute a select in mySQL that give me an output like this:

```
  PK |  IDs | name1 | name2
    -------------------
   1 |  1   |  a    |  x
   2 |  1   |  a    |  x
   3 |  2   |  b    |  y
   4 |  3   |  c    |  z
   5 |  2   |  b    |  y
   6 |  1   |  a    |  x
   7 |  2   |  b    |  y
   8 |  2   |  b    |  y
```

So all the rows with the same id have the same name1 and name2 checking the one that its not null to fill it, if there is no one, it will continue as null.

Comment: Is there ever a case where an `id` might have different values in either column?

Comment: What do you mean? That two name1= a have different ids? If you mean that, thats not posible, names are correct or null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have one value of `name1` or `name2` for a given `ID` value, you can use an aggregation function like `MAX` (or `MIN`) which will give you that value from all the value for that `IDs` in the table. Using a derived table with those values, you can `JOIN` to the original table to get the `name1` and `name2` values for each `PK`, `IDs` combination:

```
SELECT d.PK, d.IDs, m.name1, m.name2
FROM data d
JOIN (SELECT IDs, MAX(name1) AS name1, MAX(name2) AS name2
      FROM data
      GROUP BY IDs) m ON m.IDs = d.IDs
```

Output:

```
PK  IDs     name1   name2
1   1       a       x
2   1       a       x
3   2       b       y
4   3       c       z
5   2       b       y
6   1       a       x
7   2       b       y
8   2       b       y
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2b7bc04/3)

Comment: That just what i need, but if instead of just null, names could be null or ' '. The max() solución could work?

Comment: @Fernaku yes, `MAX` will still work as any string with characters is greater than an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use *correlated* sub-query :

```
select t.pk, t.ids,
       coalesce(t.name1, (select t1.name1 
                          from table t1 
                          where t1.pk < t.pk and t1.name1 is not null 
                          order by t1.pk desc 
                          limit 1)
                ) as name1,
       coalesce(t.name2, (select t1.name2 
                          from table t1 
                          where t1.pk < t.pk and t1.name2 is not null 
                          order by t1.pk desc 
                          limit 1)
                ) as name2
from table t;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `update` with `join`:

```
update t join
       (select id, max(name1) as name1, max(name2) as name2
        from t
        group by id
       ) tt
       on t.id = tt.id
    set t.name1 = coalesce(t.name1, tt.name1),
        t.name2 = coalesce(t.name2, tt.name2)
    where t.name1 is null or t.name2. is null;
```

Note:  This will not change any values that are not `NULL`, so it is safe even if the values differ for a given `id`.

Comment: But i dont want to update the table, just get an output like that final table.